# Displaying a value on the header of every page without a page refresh at all

Tags: php

I need to display some value (*net amount* maintained by a shopping cart and number of items in the cart) on the header of every page. When a new item is added to the cart or deleted or the cart is updated, the updated value should be displayed on the header with no page refresh by the user.

I think, I need to reload the page right after it finishes loading. I tried the following.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH"; CONTENT="1";URL=ShoppingCart.php">
```

but it refreshes the page on every second which is indeed not required. Also tried using `header()` something like this but it's not suitable `header("Location: #");`

Is there a way to do so? Any time the cart is updated, it should be reflected on the header of every page without a page refresh?

Comment: What do you mean by 'header'?  Do you mean in the HTTP headers of the response?  The `<head>` element of the HTML in the response content?  A particular element that appears at the top of the page?

Comment: @Phoenix: He means physical header of a page

Comment: By `header` I simply mean the header part of the page.

Comment: Roman is right.  The only way you can modify the contents of a page after it's loaded is via javascript.  Be forewarned, though, that learning AJAX and jQuery will take some time and effort; if you're not familiar with AJAX already, it's not something we can really explain how to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use AJAX. Use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). It's very simple, handy and nice!